# Pages moved from second document won't face each other as spread

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

I've combined several documents, all of which have spreads, but where the two sets of pages meet, the first and last pages remain as singles instead of combining as a spread. There's no ability to drag them together, so I'm a bit stumped.

[image: Pages refusing to face each other]

Comment: I'm not sure I know what is going on, but you could try this: **1.** Select both pages **2.** Right-click one of the pages and make sure `Allow document pages to shuffle` is enabled (my guess is that it's not) **3.**  Right-click one of the pages again and turn on `Allow selected spreads to shuffle`.

Comment: Note that the `Allow Document Pages to Shuffle ` *check mark*, in the menu means very little it doesn't appear to always correlate to the actual panel functions. So, merely toggling that setting may help.

Comment: Thank you, weirdly, toggling off `Allow selected spreads to shuffle` enabled me to grab the pages and stick them together, though they still spring apart if I turn it back on..

Comment: Luckily this issue won't have any effect on print where you normally deliver a single paged PDF. So I guess it's because you need to make some screen PDF in spreads? You could export a single paged document set to be *shown* as spreads (*Two-Up (Cover Page)*) in Acrobat. Or maybe you just want to tidy up, I get that.

Comment: @friendly_llama there's a symbiotic relationship between `Allow SPREADS to shuffle` and `Allow PAGES to Shuffle` -- Often if spread shuffle is on, pages *can't* be shuffled freely. It's somewhat logical because if you want spreads, then pages need to be correctly configured and INDD is *trying* to prevent some user error. You can often simply turn them *both* off/on and configure things how you want. It's convoluted and not easily detailed (because the menu checkmarks aren't consistent), but if you toggle the settings, eventually you can do whatever you want with pages and spreads.

Answer (score 1):

About a year late, but I was running into the same issue. I right clicked on the first page of the moved pages and selected the **Numbering & Section Options** then unchecked the **Start Section**. That solved the issue for me.

Comment: Starting a new section *can* interfere for page numbering. You may just need to toggle the `Allow pages and/or spreads to shuffle` options.